# Value changes not firing in an angular unit test

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, unit-testing, jasmine

I am trying to unit test my binding between to form inputs that is, voice phone number and sms phone number. The desired behaviour is that entering voice phone number should also populate the sms phone number but I am struggling to write a unit test for this functionality.

As you can see if I have tried a bunch of stuff so far that is :

- using fakeAsync
- Patching Value and providing value via the nativeElement.value route.
- component.ContactForm.updateValueAndValidity() func to fire an event for the changes
- Tried console logging the val of voice phone number just before expect which is working I can
  see the value has been patched successfully but however valueChanges still doesnt get triggered
  and test keeps on failing.

```js
beforeEach(() => {
  fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ContactAddEditComponent);
  fixture.detectChanges();
  component = fixture.componentInstance;
  component.ContactForm = new FormGroup({
    FirstName: new FormControl(''),
    LastName: new FormControl(''),
    VoicePhoneNumber: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    // SMSPhoneNumber: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(10), Validators.minLength(10)])],
    SMSPhoneNumber: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    Email: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    groups: new FormControl([]),
    channel: new FormControl(0, Validators.required)
  });
  fixture.detectChanges();
});

it('should create', () => {
  expect(component).toBeTruthy();
});

it('Entering VoicePhoneNumber should also populate SMSPhoneNumber ', () => {
  component.ContactForm.patchValue({
    VoicePhoneNumber: "(647) 704-3898"
  });
  // const voiceNumberInput = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#voiceNumberInput')).nativeElement;
  // const smsNumberInput = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#smsNumberInput')).nativeElement;
  // voiceNumberInput.value = '(647) 704-XXXX'
  // voiceNumberInput.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
  // tick(3000);
  component.ContactForm.updateValueAndValidity();

  fixture.detectChanges();
  console.log(component.ContactForm.controls.VoicePhoneNumber.value);
  console.log(component.ContactForm.controls.SMSPhoneNumber.value);
  // console.log(smsNumberInput.value);
  expect(component.ContactForm.controls.SMSPhoneNumber.value).toBe(component.ContactForm.controls.VoicePhoneNumber.value);
  // const smsNumberInput = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#smsNumberInput')).nativeElement;
  // console.log(smsNumberInput.value);
})
```

part from component.ts that should be getting executed in order to make the test successful

```js
async ngOnInit() {
 this.ContactForm.get('VoicePhoneNumber').valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
      //console.log(value)
      if (value != null) {
        let voicelen = value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/g, "").replace(" ", '');
        let smslen = this.f.SMSPhoneNumber.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/g, "").replace(" ", '').length;
        //console.log(this.f.SMSPhoneNumber.value);
        if (smslen == 0 && voicelen.length == 10) {
          this.voiceNumberEntered = true;
          this.ContactForm.patchValue({
            SMSPhoneNumber: value
          });
        }
      }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You subscribe in the `ngOnInit` method. `fixture.detectChanges();` triggers it. Since you make changes on ContactForm before ngOnInit is called, you don't receive the event.

```
  component.ngOnInit(); // <== this before updating form
  component.ContactForm.patchValue({
    VoicePhoneNumber: "(647) 704-3898"
  });
  tick(); // <== this to wait for the subscribe to trigger
  expect(component.ContactForm.controls.SMSPhoneNumber.value).toBe(component.ContactForm.controls.VoicePhoneNumber.value);
```

Comment: hi i tried this solution and what you said does make sense. so, thank you for the explanation. However on trying the solution I am getting. 
Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'replace')

Comment: that means you are doing `myVar.replace`, and the compiler says `myVar is null`. I guess `this.f.SMSPhoneNumber` is null